# How to include an external PHP script?

Tags: external-scripts

I have PHP file and I need to include that PHP file in static page. Where is best place to store that PHP file so I can include it in a static page.

Comment: which type of static page you are talking. Is that page created by admin or any other file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if it is totally static page, and PHP file is external, then it has nothing to do with Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

If that's your code, transform it into Drupal [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules). If you want use PHP API delivered by external service - transform it into library (move code into  sites/all/libraries/yourLibrary) and write custom module which loads files on demand (with [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1342238)).

Comment: What if its not my code and some library like the `twitteroauth`??

Comment: @SanjokGurung Use Composer to manage your dependencies, either via Composer Manager module, or make use of composer for entire project with https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/